# Size of messages in timing attack on RSA Montgomery

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, cryptocurrency, cryptographic-hardware, montgomery-multiplication

I'm codin' timing attack on RSA Montgomery which compares two sets ( the first one includes those which need a reduction in contrary to the second one ). But I got troubles with the Montgomery multiplication, I used sets of 15000 random Messages ( size: 120 bits ) and there is no reduction for a complete key of 128 bits! ( Modul N is 128 bits size).

Question what is the recommended size for random messages?

Comment: 2048-bit is the modern baseline for moduli, and random messages. But I do not see that it can be the source of your issue.